# Does sending Android app for internal testing requires store listing?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm a contract developer working on an Android app on behalf of a customer. I have a build ready for them to test and want to publish it for Internal testing.

When I try to do this, it appears as though I am blocked by numerous issues. It wants me to create store listings, provide privacy policies, fill out long questionnaires about data collection and privacy, etc.

I understand the need for all of this before releasing an app to the public, but is it really required just to publish an internal test build? Maybe I'm reading it wrong.

I tried to fill out some of it, but since I am merely the app developer and not the owner of the app, there are a lot of questions I can't answer.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: How do they want to test deploy it?  If they want to use the Play Store, yes.  If they're ok with just sideloading an apk file, no.